# How to create sql constraints in my table

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints, oracle-sqldeveloper

i have this table:

```
id | product_group_id | percentage
1  | 1                | 0.2
2  | 1                | 0.3
3  | 1                | 0.5
4  | 2                | 0.4
5  | 2                | 0.6
```

I want to know if there is a way to create constraints that for each product_group_id the percentage will be equal to 1 ( if product_group_id = 1 so 0.2 + 0.3 + 0.5 = 1).
For example if i will change the percentage where id = 2 to 0.8 or 0.1, the update (or insert) will fail because the sum is not 1.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: And what if a product has 1/3? This number will be rounded when represented in percent, making it impossible to achieve 1.

Comment: @Andre What do you mean?

Comment: @Ofer that you will have to deal with rounding errors.

Comment: what database are you using? Create a trigger associated with this table to check the constraint.

Comment: How would you add the first row in a group?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would generally make more sense to enforce this sort of constraint in the API you build on top of the table to manipulate the percentages.  Assuming, of course, that each `product_group_id` will be manipulated by at most one session at a time.

If you do really want to enforce this sort of restriction, you could create a materialized view that refreshes on commit and create a constraint on that materialized view.  Something like

```
SQL> create table table_name(
  2    id number primary key,
  3    product_group_id number,
  4    percentage number
  5  );

Table created.

SQL> create materialized view log on table_name;

Materialized view log created.

SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  create materialized view mv_table_name
  2    refresh on commit
  3  as
  4  select product_group_id, sum(percentage) total_percentage
  5    from table_name
  6*  group by product_group_id
SQL> /

Materialized view created.

SQL> alter table mv_table_name
  2    add( constraint sum_of_1 check( total_percentage = 1 ));

Table altered.
```

That will allow you to insert rows that sum to 1

```
SQL> insert into table_name values( 1, 1, 0.5 );

1 row created.

SQL> insert into table_name values( 2, 1, 0.5 );

1 row created.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.
```

and will throw an error when you try to commit changes that cause the sum to be something other than 1

```
SQL> insert into table_name values( 3, 1, 0.1 );

1 row created.

SQL> commit;
commit
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-12008: error in materialized view refresh path
ORA-02290: check constraint (SCOTT.SUM_OF_1) violated
```

Note that this is checked at commit time which is what you really need since you'll need to violate the constraint during a transaction when you want to insert multiple rows.

And, as has been pointed out, if there is the possibility of rounding errors, you probably want the `CHECK` constraint to allow sums that are 1 +/- some small epsilon (i.e between 0.999999 and 1.000001)